# How much can news events affect the volatility of a currency relative to another?

Tags: volatility, currency, news

GBPUSD is usually more volatile than USDCAD. However during U.S related news releases like the NFP, is it possible for the USDCAD to experience significantly more volatility than the GBPUSD?

Comment: You could sort of rationalize it by the fact that CA as a neighbor of US is more affected by US economic news than the GB economy.